# This variable is within a class, and I would like to call it/use it from a different class, please

Tags: android, variables, dart, flutter

```
 Future<String> getData() async {
if (!email.contains("@")) {
  print("invalid email");
}

print("Your email is " + email + " and your password is " + password);
http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.encodeFull("https://api.wkend-eve.com/auth/login"),
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
    body: {"email": email, "password": password});

Map<String, dynamic> x = json.decode(response.body);
print(x["access_token"]);
print(x["expires_in"]);
print(response.statusCode);


String acess_token = x["access_token"];
```

// I would like to call the variable :
 **String acess_token = x["access_token"];**
from another class

Answer (score 0):

Create a class **Common** and create a static variable in that class **accessToken**:

```
Common.accessToken
```

You can then use the accessToken throughout the app.